# Recover an Android project from an installed app

Tags: android, android-studio, recover, file-recovery

Recently I've switched to windows 10 by performing a clean install, which means that I've wiped the whole HDD. Sadly I forgot to backup a project built up in Android Studio but I have it installed and running on my phone.

Is it possible to somehow recover my project from what is installed on my smart device?

If yes, how?

Comment: extract your apk @KDX2

Comment: [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: Lesson learned: save early and often and Use source control. Sorry to hear that though, decompiling your app isn't perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1. Generate an apk from the installed app on your "smart" phone.**

Use [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup) to do this. There are several other apps that allow you to create apk installers from installed apps. Just search on play store for "backup apps".

**Step 2. Decompile your app to get the source code:**

This is already answered on [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) (several options)

**(Optional) Step 3. Backup on source control right away**

Use free source control services like bitbucket to backup and avoid hassles like these in future.

Answer (score 1):

try this step:
step1 : open this http://www.javadecompilers.com/

step2: upload apk on this site

step3: decompile it

step4: get your project in zip folder.